# Loading ArrayList URL into ViewHolder

Tags: java, android, arraylist, android-viewholder

Currently I'm loading images from my drawable resource folder into my `ViewHolder` by doing the following:

In my fragment I set the ArrayList like:

```
private ArrayList<Category> getCategory() {
    ArrayList<Category> categories=new ArrayList<>();
    Category category;

    category = new Category(R.string.string1, R.drawable.thumb1);
    categories.add(category);

    category = new Category(R.string.string2, R.drawable.thumb2);
    categories.add(category);

    category = new Category(R.string.string3, R.drawable.thumb3);
    categories.add(category);

    category = new Category(R.string.string4, R.drawable.thumb4);
    categories.add(category);

    category = new Category(R.string.string5, R.drawable.thumb5);
    categories.add(category);

    category = new Category(R.string.string6, R.drawable.thumb6);
    categories.add(category);

    return categories;
}
```

Here the `ArrayList<Category>` I'm referring to above:

```
public class Category {
    private int name;
    private int image;

    public Category(int name, int image) {
        this.name = name;
        this.image = image;

    }

    public int getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(int name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(int image) {
        this.image = image;
    }
}
```

In my `RecyclerView.Adapter` inside of `onBindViewHolder` I set the images to the `ViewHolder` by doing the following:

```
Picasso.with(c).load(category.get(position).getImage()).into(holder.img);
```

---

The above works perfectly, It loads the images I selected from my drawable resource folder into my `ViewHolder`'s ImageView.

**My Question:**

How can I use the same logic above to load images from a url instead of drawable. I have tried replacing `R.drawable.thumb1` with a URL.

Comment: URL supposed to be `String`. So type of image should be `String`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

For loading the images from Drawable you used the get/set for images as integer.
But for loading the url instead of drawable you have to use get/set as string as,

In you **Category** class

```
private String image;

public String getImage() {
    return image;
}

public void setImage(String image) {
    this.image = image;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To get the desired behaviour , as you said load image URL  just like you did for drawable . you need to modify you Category class as belows

```
public class Category {
public int name;
public int image;

//private member string variable as urls are String type
public String imageURl;


public Category(int name, int image) {
    this.name = name;
    this.image = image;

}

//constructor overloading which will take image name and image URL 
public Category(int name, String image) {
    this.name = name;
    this.imageURl = image;

}

public int getName() {
    return name;
}

public int getImage() {
    return image;
}

public String getImageUrl() {
    return imageURl;
}
```

}

Now in the `getCategory()` method use this constructor whenever you want to load image from URL

```
category = new Category(R.string.string1, "your image url");
categories.add(category);
```

Now for loading image with Picasso for both drawable and URL needs a Tweak , you need to check whether its image url(String type) or drawable(int type) .

```
if(category.get(position).imageURl !=null){
  Picasso.with(context).load(category.get(position).imageURl).into(imageView);

}else{
 Picasso.with(c).load(category.get(position).image).into(holder.img);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please change in your model class Image data type to String Because you are currently passing integer value to Picasso.load() it should be string

```
Picasso.with(this)
    .load("YOUR IMAGE URL HERE")
    .placeholder(Your Drawable Resource) //this is optional the image to display while the url image is downloading
    .error(Your Drawable Resource)         //this is also optional if some error has occurred in downloading the image this image would be displayed
    .into(imageView);
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets have example use newapi get key from them parse image and headlines
Make Model class which matches with APi Json Format.Something like this.

```
    },
"bar": {
  "type": "integer"
},
"baz": {
  "type": "boolean"
}
```

}
}
Make matching model class of above json below.I have made for New APi not for above json.

```
package com.bytelogs.antarikshdemo;
import java.util.List;
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class News {

    @SerializedName("status")
    @Expose
    private String status;
    @SerializedName("source")
    @Expose
    private String source;
    @SerializedName("sortBy")
    @Expose
    private String sortBy;
    @SerializedName("articles")
    @Expose
    private List<Article> articles = null;

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public String getSource() {
        return source;
    }

    public void setSource(String source) {
        this.source = source;
    }

    public String getSortBy() {
        return sortBy;
    }

    public void setSortBy(String sortBy) {
        this.sortBy = sortBy;
    }

    public List<Article> getArticles() {
        return articles;
    }

    public void setArticles(List<Article> articles) {
        this.articles = articles;
    }

}
```

Then Declare Recycler View in activity_main.xml
like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/newsList"
    tools:context="com.bytelogs.antarikshdemo.NewsActivity">

</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
```

Then Make Sample RecyclerView item layout like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="180dp"
            android:id="@+id/newsImage"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/dummy"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/newsTitle"
            android:text="@string/app_name"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            android:padding="4dp"
            />


    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Then MainActivity retrive api images and headlines and set them into views like this below.

```
package com.bytelogs.antarikshdemo;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;

public class NewsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static String url = "https://newsapi.org/v1/articles?source=the-times-of-india&sortBy=top&apiKey=<API_KEY_HERE>";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_news);

        final RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.newsList);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {

                GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
                Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();
                News news = gson.fromJson(response,News.class);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(new NewsAdapter(NewsActivity.this,news.getArticles()));

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            }
        });

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);

    }
}
```

Comment: This is not what I asked at all. You are showing me how to parse JSON, I did not mention JSON anywhere in my question nor did I mention anything about a API. The solution was simple I was getting a `int` instead of a `string`

Comment: You told need images from url so I supposed news Api which has Api in it